# How to run a long process in ASP.NET Core Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I built a program running on ASP.NET Core. And I need to do a lot of calculations and process a long time.

And I create a controller and api that if this link is opened by Cronjob, this operation will start and finally return ok will be done.

But unfortunately, the browser or any requester has 30 second timeouts
I set my ASP.NET Core timeout to 50 minutes but it didn't help.

I do not know what to do so that when my api is called first return ok is done and then everything else is done in the background

Comment: Take help of libraries like `HangFire` rather than trying a work around.

Comment: @RavikumarB No-one needs to use HangFire, imo - everything anyone needs is already built-in to ASP.NET Core.